# Upper case in address format

Tags: civimember, contacts, addresses, address-labels

Addresses are printing in upper case even though the data in the table is in title case: i.e. NEW YORK vs. New York

I can't seem to find a setting that will allow labels and address blocks in message templates to be all title case. What am I missing?

thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to Print these - are you trying in PDF generate or using labels ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the address standardization functionality with the USPS, it will return all addresses in upper case. This likely isn't your problem as you state the data appears in title, but I think it's worth flagging for those with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Some fonts show lower case letters looking like upper case (although slightly smaller), so it might be worth experimenting with another font

Answer (score 0):

Yo @James Bradach and @GrannyKat ! A good answer to this question, and two solutions to the problem, are at
[Is there a way to prevent USPS address standardization from making addresses all caps in PDF letters?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-usps-address-standardization-from-making-addresses-all/7184#7184) .